# How to get started in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing

I just read this blog post about [Machine Learning](https://digitalpolar.com/machine-learning/), [Clustering](https://digitalpolar.com/clustering/) and [Cluster Computing](https://digitalpolar.com/cluster-computing/).

My question is, how do I get started in Machine Learning ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have basic knowledge of Calculus, Statistics, Probability, and Linear Algebra.

After that, you can build a roadmap for your career, or maybe you can find some Machine Learning roadmaps on google.

Machine Learning by Andrew NG is also a good course to start.

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering off-topic questions, as advised in the community guidelines - see [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)